# Bootstrap modals aren't populating properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

so i have a few modals that are supposed to have their own content based off the content box they reference. When a user clicks the enlarge button(button that looks like a grey 'X') the modal should pop up with that information in it, but instead every modal just has the first modals information in them. I believe I've narrowed it down to the javascript but I'm not exactly sure what is wrong with it because I think it should work. Anyways here is the codepen which has ALL the code, including css, html and javascript or just the javascript code below. Also you can change the content in the first and third modal by clicking the view dropdown button and choosing either map or table. Thanks

Codepen: http://codepen.io/MarkBond/pen/VLpXjB

JAVASCRIPT:

```
        // Get all list options
    var listOptions = $('ul.dropdown-menu > li > a');

    // Attach "click" event
    listOptions.click(function(ev) {
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      var divToShow = $(href);

      // Find divs with content
      var contentDivs = divToShow.parent().find('.content');

      // Toggle "active" classes
      contentDivs.removeClass('active');
      divToShow.addClass('active');
    });

//THIS IS WHERE I THINK THE START OF THE PROBLEM IS
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('[data-target="#enlargeElementModal"]').on('click', function() {
        $('#enlargeElementModal .modal-body').html($('.content.active').html());
      });
      $('[data-target="#enlargeStrategyModal"]').on('click', function() {
        $('#enlargeStrategyModal .modal-body').html($('.content.active').html());
      });

      $('[data-target="#enlargeVariableModal"]').on('click', function() {
        $('#enlargeVariableModal .modal-body').html($('.content.active').html());
      });
    });
//END OF WHERE I THINK PROBLEM IS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this part `$('.content.active').html()`. That snippet finds first such DOM element which happens to be closer to the first "Enlarge" button. You have to be more exact with the selector. For example, provide IDs for `.ibox-content` divs and change the selector to `$('#ibox-1 .content.active').html()`.

Here's your pen modified - http://codepen.io/h8every1/pen/oXZVey. 
It still has some issues withe the middle part, but hope you'll manage to fix it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew something like that was the problem so thanks for shedding light on it. I also just added an id="ibox-2" to the middle part and it works 100%. So as i said before thank you!